# .NET 2.0 : File.AppendAllText(...) - Thread safe implementation

Tags: c#, file-io, .net-2.0, thread-safety

As an exercise in idle curiosity more than anything else, consider the following simple logging class:

```
internal static class Logging
{
    private static object threadlock;

    static Logging()
    {
        threadlock = new object(); 
    }

    internal static void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (threadlock)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\logfile.log", message);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ...handle logging errors...
        }
    }
}
```

Is the `lock` needed around `File.AppendAllText(...)` or is the method inherently thread-safe by its own implementation ?

Searching for information on this yields a lot of contradictory information, some say yes, some say no.  MSDN says nothing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`File.AppendAllText` is going to acquire an exclusive write-lock on the log file, which would cause any concurrent thread attempting to access the file to throw an exception. So yes, you need a static lock object to prevent multiple threads from trying to write to the log file at the same time and raising an `IOException`.

If this is going to be an issue, I'd really suggest logging to a database table which will do a better job of handling concurrent log writers.

Alternatively, you can use [`TextWriterTraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx) which is thread-safe (well, it's going to do the locking for you; I'd rather write as little of my own multithreaded code as possible).

Comment: This is contradictory. If File.AppendAllText has an exclusive write-lock, why do you need a separate lock?

Comment: You misunderstood, it is the file that is locked for write. So any other threads trying to write at the same time will receive an exception. To prevent that, you must serialize the writes using a lock in your program.

Comment: Don't waste your precious database resources for logging if you are using a heavy relational database otherwise if you are using a lite nosql database then it's not bad to log in the database. Use something like the windows event log if you have want to log locally, but not write to the file system yourself. But why not write a new file per log rather than append if you need to be thread safe and non-blocking?

Answer (score 2):

Testing parallel writes shows that you would get a System.IO.IOException if you were to comment out your lock statement.

```
[Test]
public void Answer_Question()
{
    var ex = Assert.Throws<AggregateException>(() => Parallel.Invoke(
        () => Logging.WriteLog("abc"),
        () => Logging.WriteLog("123")
    ));

    // System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Logs\thread-safety-test.txt' because it is being used by another process.
    Console.Write(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is thread safe in the sense that it opens the file with Read sharing, so assuming your filesystem honors file locks, only one thread will be allowed to write to the file at a time.  Other threads may, however, get dirty reads if they are attempting to read the same file.

Comment: And other threads will throw exceptions when trying to write.