# A task was canceled on the await call (POST) due to timeout when response from server (Python flask) is too quick

Tags: c#, flask, httprequest, uwsgi, .net-4.8

**UPDATE 3:**
After reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73424728/13181058) to a different post, I started a different experiment. If I change the answer coming from the Python (flask) server to 100, I can reproduce the error in my computer. In this case, all the calls get cancelled due to time out. So this made me thing about adding a delay in the API before sending back a 200. After adding 100 milliseconds of delay, now **every single call** gets completed. Calls that originally took 9 milliseconds, now are taking 109 milliseconds **but** are not **Canceled** anymore. They get **RanToCompletion**
I ran this program simultaneously 15 times, and all the calls await correctly if the 100 miliseconds delay is in place before the API response. Without the delay, even running it once will result in many of the 10 calls being **Cancelled**. Still don't understand what's causing this.

**UPDATE 2:**
I think I am into somethig now.
I have created a much simpler program:

```
public class Program
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someuser:somepass"))}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await PostSomething(i.ToString()).ContinueWith(x=> log(x.Status.ToString(), "0"));
        }
    }

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostSomething(string tower)
    {
        var RequestUri = new Uri("someAPI");
        string json = "somejson";    
        var msg = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return
            await client.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);
    }


    public static void log(string line, string where)
    {
        string logPath = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)}\\log";
        if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
        }
        string mnth = $"{logPath}\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM") + "-" + where + ".txt";
        string time = Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        File.AppendAllText(mnth, time + " " + line);
    }
}
```

Which runs absolutelly **normal** in my computer:

```
Run 1:
    2022-11-30 11:27:33 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:33 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:33 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:33 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:33 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:33 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:33 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:34 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:34 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:34 RanToCompletion

Run 2:    
    2022-11-30 11:27:46 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:47 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:47 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:47 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:47 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:47 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:47 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:47 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:47 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:48 RanToCompletion

 Run 3:   
    2022-11-30 11:27:57 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:58 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:58 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:58 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:58 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:58 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:58 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:58 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:58 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 11:27:59 RanToCompletion
```

However, when I run the program multiple times in one of the computers I am having trouble with, the **result varies**:

```
Run 1:
    2022-11-30 03:19:26 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:19:36 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:19:46 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:19:56 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:20:06 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:20:16 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:20:26 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:20:28 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:20:38 Canceled

Run 2:    
    2022-11-30 03:22:55 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:23:05 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:23:15 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:23:25 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:23:27 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:23:28 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:23:38 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:23:48 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:23:57 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:23:58 RanToCompletion

Run 3:   
    2022-11-30 03:29:43 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:29:44 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:29:54 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:29:57 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:29:57 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:30:07 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:30:17 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:30:19 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:30:29 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:30:39 Canceled
 
Run 4:   
    2022-11-30 03:35:57 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:36:07 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:36:17 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:36:19 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:36:20 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:36:30 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:36:39 RanToCompletion
    2022-11-30 03:36:49 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:36:59 Canceled
    2022-11-30 03:37:01 RanToCompletion
```

For all those **http requests**, I can see on the server that they **all** came back **200**.

*How come some of those tasks weren't ran to completion? Where could I find more details about this?*

They get canceled after 10 seconds, which is the set **timeout** on the HttpClient. *But why a timeout?* The request got back **200**, so how can it timeout?

**UPDATE 1:**
I have tried different methods, but it fails **really often** when awaiting for the http response. I could do 100 calls to the api, all of them will get through and POST correctly. However, if I **await** for the response in order to write this to a file, for example, it will fail sometimes after the first call is back, sometimes after the second, sometimes won't even get the first response back. Again, this doesn't happen ob my PC, only in some other PCs (Windows 10, Windows 7).

I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var res4 = await PostAsync(i.ToString());   
    log(res4 + " in loop", "4"); 
}

public static async Task<string> PostAsync(string num)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    ...some http header, uri,json...
    var msg = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    //This next line is when it usually fails. I have tried without ConfigureAwait(false) too
    var resp = await httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
    log($"POST Awaited {num}", "1");
    //I tried both with ConfigureAwait(false) and without
    var resp2 = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    log($"Read Awaited {num}", "1");
    return resp2;
}


public static void log(string line, string where)
{
    string logPath = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)}\\log";
    if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
    }
    string mnth = $"{logPath}\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM") + "-" + where + ".txt";
    string time = Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    File.AppendAllText(mnth, time + " " + line);
}
```

**Original question:**

As sugested by @Jodrell, I have tried a **more appropriate approach**.
Now I have a class:

```
public class BaseApiController
{
    protected async Task<string> AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someuser:somepass"))}");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        var RequestUri = new Uri("someserver", "someAPI");

        string json = "somejson";

        var msg = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);

        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then I have:

```
public class TestController: BaseApiController
{
    public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        var data = await AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync();

        return data;
    }
}
```

And a function that writes into a file:

```
private static async Task logASync(string line, string where)
{
    string logPath = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)}\\log";
    string path = $"{logPath}\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM") + "-" + where + ".txt";

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(path), path, "Was null or whitepsace.");

    //If doesn't exist, CreateDirectory does nothing
    Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);

    using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        //Do we need ConfigureAwait?
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(line).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await writer.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

And I call them like:

```
TestController testController = new TestController();
var res1 = await testController.Post();
await logASync("Some message", "1");
Thread.Sleep(100);
var res2 = await testController.Post();
await logASync("Some message", "1");
Thread.Sleep(100);
var res3 = await testController.Post();
await logASync("Some message", "1");
Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Again, this **works perfectly in my computer**. File gets created if doesn't exits, and 3 times "Some message" appears in the file.
However, when I do this in a different computer, only the first message and call are successfully performed.
Then I get this **exception**:

```
2022-11-29 01:06:24 System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TestRequest.BaseApiController.<AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in line 178
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TestRequest.TestController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext() in line 230
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TestRequest.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in line 44
```

line 178 is:

```
var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);
```

line 230 is:

```
var data = await AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync();
```

line 44 is:

```
var res2 = await testController.Post();
```

I don't understand why this is working in my computer but not in several other computers. I am using the same VPN they are using.
Is this related to I/O? Is there anything I can do in Windows to get more information about why this is happening?

I have also tried writing each time in a different file like:

```
TestController testController = new TestController();
var res1 = await testController.Post();
await logASync("Some message", "1");
Thread.Sleep(100);
var res2 = await testController.Post();
await logASync("Some message", "2");
Thread.Sleep(100);
var res3 = await testController.Post();
await logASync("Some message", "3");
Thread.Sleep(100);
```

but the same happens.

Comment: `AppendAllText` is not thread safe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809843/net-2-0-file-appendalltext-thread-safe-implementation

Comment: `async void` is a sign you are doing wrong, that is not an event handler, right?

Comment: Is your log server responding? Maybe you get the timeout, simply because the server doesn't answer your request. Maybe because the server is slow or the network connection breaks somewhere on the way.

Comment: @Jodrell, no it is not. So what is the right way of doing it? I would love to get a hold on this, specially if it means I'm following better practices.

Comment: @Oliver, from my computer I have never encountered this problem. Never. It happens just in some older machines. I am even using the same VPN they use.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Comment: @Jodrell. Thank you. I have updated the original question with a more approapiate approach. Still the same result.

Comment: @CarlosMira but now you can see the exception occurring.

Comment: @Jodrell. I do. I have been doing more test and my conclusion is that when I run the software in the other machine(s), they don't await for the .Result so that's why I get that exception. However, this doesn't happen in my machine. I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: The problem is the post to the uri on , `var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);` That fails on the other machines, have you tried the same request with Postman or some such.

Comment: @Jodrell, I tried with Thunder Client and it works. It just seems to be that in those machines, the requests don't await or something goes wrong with awaiting. Sometimes I can send 2 requests and write twice on the local file, sometimes 1.

Comment: @Oliver, I updated the question with new approaches. On the last one I can see how on the remote computer I get some of the tasks cancelled but no others. Why is this not happening on my computers but on others?

Comment: I think it is a timeout or the account being used does not have the credentials to complete operation.  Because it is taking 10 seconds before failure it is more likely a timeout.

Comment: @jdweng It is indeed a timeout, but why? The API comes back with a 200 in less than 10 msecs. Why is that PostAsync not picking up the response some of the times?

Comment: You see, the request arrives at the server and the server answer with 200, but the task gets canceled in .Net. Did you check with Wireshark or something similar, that the data really arrives at the problematic PC? Maybe it is some network or firewall issue.

Comment: @Oliver, I did some more test, and after adding a delay on the server response, all the calls get back properly. No cancellations ocurr. So it has to be related to the network, I guess? Could the server reply too quickly for slower computers? It just doesn't makes much sense that I have to delay the answer.

Comment: While the additional timeout sounds awkward, I would still guess on a network problem. Thanks that you have a _switch_ to enable / disable the behaviour you should really make two network traces on server and client for each scenario and compare them. Like theodor already mentions in his answer I would go that way to hopefully find the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error localization

First thing first, I am not a HTTP expert, I have the majority of my backend experience made by doing TCP/IP backend server applications, so do not be too harsh please, but I can tell you one thing or two that could guide you. HTTP uses TCP in order to transfer information, which in turn uses the syn / ack / syn-ack handshake.

### Error Description

This means that when you send something, you wait the server to acknowledge the data that was sent, and then the server acknowledges you that the data was received. This means that your error occurs during the ack and/or syn-ack stage. This means that the receiver is either receiving the data and does not reply, which is extremely improbable, or the receiver isn't receiving the data at all or it received the data partially. This is because you are sending the data on a stream and streams don't have 100% guaranteed chances of success in their operations. The reason why, is because you are sending packets(which are some glorified chunks of binary data) on a stream(a glorified channel) that is using a protocol named HTTP which in turn uses TCP for data transmission and a fail safe mechanisms, and through which the packets sent could reach the destination intact, fragmented, or do not reach the destination at all. This is caused by the fact that the receiving or sending buffers of either the receiver or the sender, can be filled with bytes form previous requests that either the receiver or the sender can still process at the moment, making either the sender or the receiver drop the packets of its current HTTP get or post session, respectively. Another cause could be a combination of fluctuations within the data transmission speed of the network and the size of the packets sent, resulting again in either the sender or the receiver dropping the packets.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, 4 packets were sent, and from those 4, only 2 reached their destination. I used Cisco Packet Tracer, a network simulation software used for developing networks and other network engineering/backend engineering related tasks, for the scenario shown above.

```
    protected async Task<string> AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someuser:somepass"))}");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        var RequestUri = new Uri("someserver", "someAPI");

        string json = "somejson";

        var msg = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

The reason why you get the below displayed error message is a combination of multiple factors.

```
   2022-11-29 01:06:24 System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TestRequest.BaseApiController.<AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in line 178
```

### Causes Within The Implementation

1. You implemented the Task with the assumption that you will get a response every time, and as I shown earlier, packets could not be sent successfully 100% of the times, every time. Each time you send payloads, they have a certain degree of success depending on the situations, not a guaranteed chance of success.

```
    var msg = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);

    return result.ToString();
```

In the above shown section of the code you save the response value in a variable, and then return the result of the `httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);` directly. This approach is wrong, because, as I mentioned before, payload transmission procedures can fail. It is not a guaranteed chance that the payload will be received/transmitted. A fix for this issue is to set a string variable that holds an error message as the return value and change its value if the `httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);` succeeds.

```
    protected async Task<string> AsyncAwait_GetSomeDataAsync()
    {
        string return_value = "DESIRED ERROR MESSAGE";      

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someuser:somepass"))}");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        var RequestUri = new Uri("someserver", "someAPI");

        string json = "somejson";

        var msg = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(RequestUri, msg);

        if(result != null)
        {
           return_value = result.ToString();
        }

        return return_value ;
    }
```

2. You need to increase the receive and/or send buffer sizes, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=environment-tuning-tcpip-buffer-sizes. A large buffer size means less chance for factors, such as network speed fluctuations and packets that were not sent/received on time and dropped to occur, due to the fact that more packet slots are available, and thus more packets can be sent and/or received in a shorter period of time. The downside of a larger buffer size is the fact that it can make your CPU work harder, set the buffer too high and the CPU will be clogged with packages and thus, the sender or receiver will drop the packets for the current session. Tune in your receive and send buffer sizes on both the sender and recipient. Use these link to set your buffer sizes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.maxresponsecontentbuffersize?view=net-6.0

3. Another good fix is to set in your program a request retry mechanism. A mechanism like this will try a set number of times to POST and/or RECEIVE requests if failure occurs.

As you can see, a HttpClient HTTP socket, has a single option, the option to set the buffer size related to the receive buffer of the respective socket. Try to tune in the receive buffers on both the receiver and the sender.

If this still did not help you, I recommend using Sockets. HttpClient is an abstraction over the Socket class, and thus it is hiding complexities and processes that happen under the hood. With sockets you have greater control over what is happening and how, but also a lot of complexities that you have to deal with.

[C#: How to execute a HTTP request using sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862890/c-how-to-execute-a-http-request-using-sockets)

Comment: The section "Causes Within The Implementation" is exactly what I did on my 2nd and 3rd Update and how I realised that adding a delay to the server's answer made a difference. I am now trying to get some traces and see if that indicates something on the network. However, we are both using the same VPN, so I am unsure about the results

Comment: Try to increase the buffer sizes on both ends. You need to be able to capture more packets at once. The problem is that you are using the "HttpClient" class, which is an abstraction of the "Socket" class, which in turn does not have a setting to increase the send buffer size, you have an option to increase just the receive buffer size. Using Wireshark to see if packets were dropped won't help you mitigate the packet loss. Increasing the buffer sizes will. Especially because you are using VPN, which is inherently unstable.

Comment: I understand. I am really trying to find the cause for this. So, if I am also using the VPN at home, how come I am not suffering the same issue? Something to do with my network card? It seems the software runs on one of those machines, the await misses the http response most of the time. So, by delaying the response, everything seems to be fine. I will try and recreate the same program with the socket class and see what happens. So the send buffer size needs to be increased?

Comment: Both of them, because the connection (channel) on which both of them are communicating is unstable. So, if you send and receive more packets at once, it is a smaller chance that some packets will not be sent and as a result, they will be dropped and the POST or GET session will fail. Try first thing first to increase the receive and send buffer sizes on both the receiver and sender. Because you are using the "HttpClient" class, you can increase only the receive buffer size, from what I am seeing, on the receiver side try increasing the send and receive buffers if possible

Comment: If this does not help, then implement this using the "Socket" class.

Comment: I ran a trace on the computer where I was having trouble and I saw several of these: Tcp:  [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=58183, DstPort=HTTP Alternate(8080), PayloadLen=0, Seq=1714189116, Ack=2665209691, Win=515 (scale factor 0x8) = 131840, Checksum: 0x19EA, Bad,  which is something I didn't get in my computer when I did the trace. Are those the cause of this issue?
I tried increasing the receiving/transmitting buffer in the machine without exit.

Comment: The packets are corrupted, that is what it means. Checksum is used to calculate the packets sent or received. It is a value attached in the TCP header, and checked by the sender or receiver to see if the data is not corrupted. One advice related to the increase of the buffer size is to ensure that both sides have equal receive and sent buffer sizes.

Comment: The "HttpClient" class has "client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize(int value)", which increases the size of the receive buffer size, which is already big, 2GB to be exact.

Comment: From your error message it is clear that the packet was corrupted, because the length of the packet had PayloadLen=0.

Comment: The error message is not the cause of the issue, is the issue itself. The diagnostic trace result told you that, the sum of the packets does not match the size that it supposed to have, marked in the TCP header Checksum section, and thus it dropped the packet.

Comment: I repeat, it is recommended that the sender and the receiver to have equal send and receive buffer sizes, because if, for example, the client has a 500MB send buffer size, and the server has a 100MB buffer size, the rhythm in which they read and write packets will differ, and as a result, the receiver and/or sender could write and/or read the packets too slow or too fast and get out of sync and drop some packets.

Comment: And again, nothing is guaranteed, that's why TCP has so many error prevention methods. The idea is to minimise the packet loss, not to eliminate it. It is impossible to have a 100% success rate.

Comment: Awarded your answer because you pointed me in the right direction. Thank you!